# How to make the fonts of the legends in Netlogo bigger

Tags: plot, fonts, netlogo

I am looking for a way to modify the visual representation in Netlogo. My screen size is small, so when I want to capture a screenshot of  my simulation result, the legends are not much readable. Even making the windows bigger does not affect the fonts. I wish there was also a way to make the curves in a plot thicker.

Any ideas?
Thanks,

Comment: have you tried the Zoom menu?

Comment: Thanks. By making the whole window bigger, I lose most of the view as my screen is small.